# Saved video as input instead of Camera in android

Tags: android, opencv

I've implemented an android app that implements the CvCameraListener interface. In the onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) method I process the captured inputFrame from the camera. 
Now to my problem: Is there a way that I can use a saved video file on my phone as an input instead of getting the frames directly from camera? That means I would like to have a video file input frame by frame in Mat format.

Is there a possible way to do that?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: not so easy. opencv does not offer a way here.

Comment: That's unfortunate.. Is there another way to do it without opencv? For example getting bitmaps? Then i can still convert them

Comment: oh, sure, you can imwrite/imread single images to sdcard, no problem.

Comment: And you can save every second for example 3 pictures from a video file and afterwards load them into bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though it is not tested and I don't have much experience in OpenCV on Android. Still, you can try like this:

```
//[FD : File descriptor or path.]
Bitmap myBitmapFrame;
MediaMetadataRetriever video_retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(FD);
        myBitmapFrame = retriever.getFrameAtTime(..);
        }
    catch(...
          :
Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmapFrame, myCVMat);
```

You may have to implement some callback system as you can work with only OpenCV after it is initialized. Also, you can convert frame number to time-code.

Good Luck and Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I'm busy, but I will try that as soon as possible. Will give a feedback if that worked

Comment: Thanks that worked :) One question though. I recorded a video with my phone camera. But when I loop over the getFrameAtTime it somehow only returns every second an image on the view, eventhough my loop looks like retriever.getFrameAtTime(time); time += 200000; (every 0.2s one image) What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) For your next question, I need to see the code to figure it out. My suggestion is to try with few different types/encoding of video also.

Comment: It's sth like this:
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) { bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(nextFrame); nextFrame += 200000; utilis.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat); return mat; }

So i just use the onCameraFrame as a loop and then show the retrieved bitmap on the camerapreview. The video is standard recorded, nothing special. But I only get on the preview an image every second and not more.

Comment: Additionally i rotate the bitmap, because its 640*480 instead of 480*640. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Hi, Do not worry about processing like rotating, it is not a problem but it is surely IO. Try this and give me feedback: `retriever.getFrameAtTime(2 * 100000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST)`

Comment: It's not working. I've also tried out some other settings and other values instead of using nextFrame += 200000. No success. I wondered how many FPS I get. So I recorded a video showing a watch. Interestingly I got exactly 1 FPS. So with nextFrame += 100000, 200000 and 500000 I always got the same result. Also tried it with an async task to receive the frames. Same result. My guess is that the getFrameAtTime must be buggy or I'm overlooking sth.. I'm using a mp4 video of length ~20s